# Algebraic numbers dense in R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How would I show that the algebraic numbers are dense in R. I know that the rationals and irrationals are dense in R.

Answer (score 11):

HINT: Every rational number is also what kind of number?

Comment: Every rational number is an algebraic number...

Comment: @Alti: And you know that the rationals are dense, so ... ?

Comment: The algebraic numbers are dense? Is this because using the rationals, I can construct an irrational algebraic number? (Ex. multiplying w in Q by (2)^(1/2))

Comment: @Alti: You’re making this **much** too hard. A set $D$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ if every open interval $(a,b)$ contains a member of $D$. The rationals are dense, so every open interval contains a rational, and therefore automatically contains an algebraic number. Therefore?

Comment: Therefore the  algebraic numbers are dense in R. Wow, I didn't know it could be so simple. Thank you!

Comment: @Alti: You’re welcome! (Sometimes it really is simple, amazingly enough.)

Comment: You (Alti) mean the real algebraic numbers of course. Not all algebraic numbers are real, for example, $i$ is an algebraic number.